# Capslock warning on mouse hover on password field

Tags: java, vaadin7

When the **capslock button is on**, I want a warning message to be shown on mouse hover on the password field.

I found the below piece of code from VAADIN website,

```
@Connect(CapsLockWarning.class)
public class CapsLockWarningConnector extends AbstractExtensionConnector {
    @Override
    protected void extend(ServerConnector target) {
        final Widget passwordWidget = ((ComponentConnector) target).getWidget();

        final VOverlay warning = new VOverlay();
        warning.setOwner(passwordWidget);
        warning.add(new HTML("Caps Lock is enabled!"));

        passwordWidget.addDomHandler(new KeyPressHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onKeyPress(KeyPressEvent event) {
                if (isEnabled() && isCapsLockOn(event)) {
                    warning.showRelativeTo(passwordWidget);
                } else {
                    warning.hide();
                }
            }
        }, KeyPressEvent.getType());
    }

    private boolean isCapsLockOn(KeyPressEvent e) {
        return e.isShiftKeyDown() ^ Character.isUpperCase(e.getCharCode());
    }
}
```

But the above piece of code depends on **pressing any key to determine whether capslock is on or not.**

Is there any way to implement this functionality **without pressing any keys**(except capslock) in vaadin?

Please help :(

Comment: Any help or tips please???

Answer (score 0):

In AWT there is a Toolkit class which does the job

```
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
```

then you can check the state capslock

```
boolean isCapsLockOn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

Answer (score -2):

You can use `getLockingKeyState` to check if Caps Lock is currently set:

```
boolean isOn = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK);
```

**or**`setLockingKeyState` doesn't toggle the state of the key, it sets it. If you pass it true it will set the key state to on regardless of the original state:

```
Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().setLockingKeyState(KeyEvent.VK_CAPS_LOCK, true);
```

Comment: Yes i admit my mistake i thought he want some JS Code . btw thanks for alert :)